# Matrix Dimensions Do Not Agree

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I keep on getting a matrix size error because 'lin_bayer' is three dimensions, while 'mask' is two dimensions. I'm thinking of padding 'mask' in order to fix this. The other solution I can think of is to make my own manual white-balance matrix, by setting the RGB values to equal each other. What do you think about these two solutions? Any suggestions?

```
    wb_multipliers = [2.124023, 1, 1.558594];
    xyz2cam = [ 6444 -904 -893;
        -4563 12308 2535;
        -903 2016 6728]/10000;

    % - - - Read image into MATLAB - - -
    raw = single(imread(filename));

    % - - - Linearize - - -
    lin_bayer = (raw-black)/(saturation-black);
    lin_bayer = max(0,min(lin_bayer,1));
    clear raw

    % - - - White Balance - - -
    mask = wbmask(size(lin_bayer,1),size(lin_bayer,2),...
                            wb_multipliers,'rggb');
    balanced_bayer = lin_bayer .* mask;
    clear lin_bayer mask
```

Comment: `bsxfun(@times,lin_bayer,mask)`, assuming `mask` is of the same size as one 3D slice in `lin_bayer`? `bsxfun` takes care of the size-mismatch by expanding the singleton dimension(s), which in this case would be the `dim-3` in `mask`.

Comment: Hello Laura, welcome to SO! Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks...unfortunately it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Laura - What Divakar suggested should work.  You need to make sure that `lin_bayer` and `mask` are the **same** data type.  Can you please post the error that you got?  Also, do you have a function that is called `max` that you wrote, or are you using MATLAB's built-in `max` function?  If you are using MATLAB's built-in function, `lin_bayer` will **no longer** be a 3D matrix.

Comment: @rayryeng....thank you for your post. Here is my error: "Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree. Error in raw_process_test (line 86)
balanced_bayer = lin_bayer .* mask;" I am using MATLAB's built-in max function, but considering that lin_bayer is a 3D matrix of 3456x5184x3 and mask is a 2D matrix of 3456x5184, isn't MATLAB's max function supposed to make lin_bayer 2D?